# Viewing Codeview symbols

Tags: portable-executable

I have an old game executable with a large section of debug symbols, apparently in the Codeview format. How can I view the contents of this section in a human-readable format?

Answer (score 3):

Current Windows compilers do not put the content of the debug symbols into the image file itself, they only put a reference to an external symbols file into the image. They put the debug data into a separate symbols file with the PDB (Program Data Base) extension. As you mentioned it, this format is also named CodeView. In your case, it looks like (since the debug section is large) you might be confronted with a really old symbols format.

[this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100314151942/http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) explains the different symbols formats.

Comment: CFF Explorer (http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: That article was somewhat helpful; I found the NB09 code within the executable, meaning that it is in fact Codeview 4.10. It seems that CFF Explorer only allows viewing the debug directory, rather than the debug information itself.

Comment: PeDump (http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm) should help since it can dump your PE file.

Comment: It outputted:

CodeView Signature: 3930424E
Unhandled CodeView Information format NB09

Comment: Linkers. Compilers do not put the debug information into executables either way. The linker is what puts stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, given that this is for 32-bit Windows, I believe the normal Windows [symbol handler API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/symbol-handling) should be able to read the data. From there, it's pretty much a matter of deciding what data you want, and how you want it formatted.